# The first element of my array not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, while-loop

So This is my javascript code. When I run it step by step using the browser's developer tools it gets all the elements from the array but it only prints the last 4. How would I fix this?

```
function showDuties() {
  var numDuties = document.getElementById('pfJobs').value;
  var i = numDuties - 1
  var t = ""
  var pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights", 
      "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"]

  while (i >= 0) {
      document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = t;
      t += pfDuties[i] + "<br>";
      i--;  
  }
}
```

```html
<script>

window.showDuties = function() {
  var numDuties = document.getElementById('pfJobs').value;
  var i = numDuties - 1
  var t = ""
  var pfDuties = ["Auditing", "Close out registers", "Clean free weights", 
      "Sign up new members", "File paperwork"]

  while (i >= 0) {
     document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = t;
      t += pfDuties[i] + "<br>";
       
      i--;  
  }
}

</script>


<form>
 <input type="submit" value="Click here" onclick="showDuties(); return false;"> 
   to see my top 
 <input type="text" id="pfJobs" />
   job duties here.
 <p id = "pfj">
 </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you add the element BEFORE you add it to `t`. You need to move it after. And better yet, do not update it on every iteration, update it when the looping is done.

```
while (i >= 0) {
  t += pfDuties[i] + "<br>";
  i--;  
}
document.getElementById('pfj').innerHTML = t;
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! What a simply overlooked mistake. Thank you very much.